# Angular http request add port 4200 to each of my request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http

I'm using angular 6 and trying to make http post request to log a user

I serve the application with : `ng serve --aot`

On the request I have an interceptor that add a jwt token :

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor() {
    }

    /**
     * Add JWT to each requests and complete base Url
     *
     * @param {HttpRequest<any>} request
     * @param {HttpHandler} next
     * @returns {Observable<HttpEvent<any>>}
     */
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const clonedRequest = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                Accept: 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${AuthService.getToken()}`,
                url: this.completeUrl(request.url)
            }
        });
        return next.handle(clonedRequest);
    }

    /**
     * Complete base url to get full endpoints
     *
     * @param {string} url
     * @returns {string}
     */
    private completeUrl(url: string) {
        if (url.indexOf('http://') >= 0 || url.indexOf('https://') >= 0) {
            return url;
        } else {
            return environment.BASE_URL + url;
        }
    }
}
```

The login function :

```
public login({login, password}: SecurityPayload): Observable<SecurityToken> {
        return this.http.post<SecurityToken>(
            'authenticate',
            {
                user: login,
                secret: password
            },
            {}
        ).pipe(
            map((token) => {

                console.log('logged in');
                if (token) {
                    this.setToken(token);
                }
                return token;
            }),
            tap(
                // Navigate to main screen through the auth.guard
                _ => this.router.navigate(['/'])
            )
        );
    }
```

I logged the full url at `return environment.BASE_URL + url;` and it's

`http://localhost/authenticate` which is the good one

but in the browser I get a 404 with this url : `http://localhost:4200/authenticate`

Any idea ?

Comment: Why are you doing http://localhost:4200/authenticate in the browser if you assume that http://localhost/authenticate is the correct url. I think I dont understand your issue

Comment: What's the value of `request.url`? And in case you want it to work just on `localhost` and not `localhost:4200`, why don't u run `ng serve --port 80`?

Comment: That's my question the port 4200 is added out of nowhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url should not be specified in the `headers` parameters, but directly as a property of the object passed to the `clone` method

```
 intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const clonedRequest = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                Accept: 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${AuthService.getToken()}`,
                //Do not add url here
            },

            url: this.completeUrl(request.url)
        });
        return next.handle(clonedRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will not pass anything it will take the current url. also in your completeUrl method yo are checking some conditions which might return the url will port :4200

I doubt below line

`if (url.indexOf('http://') >= 0 || url.indexOf('https://') >= 0) {`

You can debug them step by step if you will just do `ng serve` (not --aot). you can set break points in the typescript class and see where the bug is.